# cannot compile and find module angular/animations

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-animations

This is my Error message, anyone can help?

> This likely means that the library (@angular/platform-browser/animations) which declares BrowserAnimationsModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if
> a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is
> expected to be compatible with Ivy.
> 37 export declare class BrowserAnimationsModule

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

My app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BooksComponent } from './books/books.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BooksComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: try rerunning `ng serve`, this usually fixes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `npm update` and try to run the application again.

It will update all the dependencies and then install them. It will also install missing dependencies if there's some.